# Python web application: How to keep state

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, web.py

I wrote a WSGI compatible web application using web.py that loads a few dozen MB data into memory during startup.

It works quite well with the web.py integrated server.

However, using Apache 2 + mod_wsgi, every single request reloads the data, essentially starting the program again. Due to the loading time of several seconds, this is unbearable.

Is it inherent to mod_wsgi or can it be configured? What are my alternatives?

Comment: Is it inherent to mod_wsgi?  No.  It's inherent in HTTP.  You'll need to post the smallest bit of code  that shows how you think "startup" works.  Also, you'll have to provide your mod_wsgi configuration, particularly, showing whether or not you're using "daemon" mode.

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks for bringing up daemon mode -- having one persistent process across requests keeps the server-side data in memory. Make it an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: Yes, likely you were using embedded mode and worse still prefork MPM, this means requests could be going to lots of processes and application needing to be loaded into a new process quite a lot. See 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html' for discussions on issues with prefork and embedded mode it you don't configure things properly.

Comment: You should actually post the smallest bit of code that shows how you think "startup" works. Also, you should provide your mod_wsgi configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is it inherent to mod_wsgi?" No. It's inherent in HTTP

Since you didn't post your mod_wsgi configuration, it's impossible to say what you did wrong.

I can only guess that you didn't use daemon mode.

See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Defining_Process_Groups for more information on daemon mode.

This may not be the best solution.  It may be better (far, far better) to use a proper database.  Without actual code examples, and more details, this is all just random guessing.

Comment: The link is broken